# Retrieve transaction details as shown on bscscan

Tags: python, api, binance, binance-smart-chain, bscscan

I am trying to retrieve info about bsc transations using Bscscan api but it appears to be very limited.

```
endpoint = "https://api.bscscan.com/api"\
   "?module=account"\
   "&action=txlistinternal"\
   "&txhash={}"\
   "&apikey={}"
```

After sending a GET request, this is what i get:

> {'status': '1', 'message': 'OK', 'result': [{'blockNumber': '19952739', 'timeStamp': '1659033895', 'from': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001000', 'to': '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead', 'value': '7802270354745452', 'contractAddress': '', 'input': '', 'type': 'call', 'gas': '2300', 'gasUsed': '0', 'isError': '0', 'errCode': ''}]}

however, on bscscan there is so much more information and already decoded, so is there a way to retrieve information as shown as bscscan?

Comment: The BSC data from api is truncated. I found it more useful to use the 'download csv' option from the site

Comment: is it possible to download csv of single transactions?

Comment: I would use BeautifulSoup and parse the html for a singular transaction. You can also look in to using the web3 lib

Answer (score 0):

https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=YOUR_ADDRESS&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=0&offset=1&sort=asc&apikey=API_KEY

In the url above, replace YOUR_ADDRESS with your bsc address example 0xaE........
Replace API_KEY with your api key.
Then copy and paste the url in your web browser. You will get the list of all transactions on that address

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).